# Increase startup threshold for k8s container in v1.12

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-container

Following the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/), I could set the threshold for container startup like so:

```
startupProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: liveness-port
  failureThreshold: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
```

Unfortunately, it seems like `startupProbe.failureThreshold` is not compatible with our current k8s version (1.12.1):

```
unknown field "startupProbe" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Is there a workaround for this? I'd like to give a container a chance of ~40+ minutes to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `startupProbe` was [introduced with 1.16](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/950) - so you cannot use it with Kubernetes 1.12.

I am guessing you are defining a `livenessProbe` - so the easiest way to get around your problem is to remove the `livenessProbe`. Most applications won't need one (some won't even need a `readinessProbe`). See also this excellent article: [Liveness Probes are Dangerous](https://srcco.de/posts/kubernetes-liveness-probes-are-dangerous.html).

Comment: How do I disable it completely? All docs are dealing with tweaking it

Comment: Just remove the element from your YAML/JSON

Comment: I can't seem to cancel the probing. I suspect there might be defaults set by our cluster administrators

Comment: It could be that there is an admission controller adding this. Have you tried removing the "livenessProbe" (and sub-elements) or setting livenessProbe: {}

Comment: I'm on GKE. It looks like Google Cloud Platform only supports up to v1.14 right now, and therefore does not support startupProbe.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a probe, you could specify `initialDelaySeconds` and make it some large value that is sufficient for your container to start up.

If you didn't care about probes at all, then you could just let it execute a command that will never fail e.g. `whoami`

Take what you need from the example below:

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - whoami
  initialDelaySeconds: 2400
  periodSeconds: 5
```

You could do the same config for `livenessProbe` if you require one.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer for this question, but can be useful...

"startupProbes" comes with k8s 1.16+.

If you are suing helm you can surround your block startupProbes with this in your template:

```
{{- if (semverCompare ">=1.16-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion) }}
startupProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: liveness-port
  failureThreshold: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
{{- end }}
```